# White screen while opening my ionic app in some devices

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

In few mobiles,my ionic app shows white screen only, when apk build with --prod mode. But the same apk works on other mobiles. If i build without --prod , it is working in all mobiles. i don't have any idea. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You already check if the app throwing a javascript error on this devices?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using android platform version 10.0.0 or higher. Then you have to remove whitelist plugin, if it is installed in your project.
It doesn't work with android 10 or later. This is the reason it shows white screen after opening installed application.

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-whitelist
cordova prepare   OR ionic cordova prepare
```

if **prepare** doesn't work try to remove platform and add again.

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova platform add android
```

Thanks, Hope it helps you.

Comment: No Not working... while initiating app we are getting error ```Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token```

Comment: @RajaSekaran Can you mantion ionic version, cordova version and android platform ?version

Comment: ionic 5, cordova 11 and android